# Circular download progress status icon

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to implement the download circular progress status same that appears when we download an app from app store which also includes pause and cancel functionalities in it. How can I implement the same using swift 3.0 for my in-house enterprise app store on iOS.
Any suggestions will be really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CAShapeLayer` of a full circle arc and a `CAAnimation` to animate the `strokeEnd` Property from zero to one.

Take a look at the clock wipe animation in my https://github.com/DuncanMC/iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo github project. That uses a shape layer as a mask on an image. You could draw a shape layer directly.